# Couples of mutually backwards-similarities, what properties do they have and are they useful?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question

Assume we have two matrices $A,B$ for which:
$$A = TDT^{-1}\\B = T^{-1}DT$$
Can we derive anything about these matrices relation to each other?

I have tried experimenting a bit but I can't see anything special:

We can see that
$$A^{k} = TD^kT^{-1}\\B^{k}=T^{-1}D^kT$$

$$AB = TDT^{-2}DT\\$$

However if we had an operation which flips all factors of matrix products *without transposing them*, then we can turn $A$ into $B$ and vice versa. But what kind of weird operation would that be?

Comment: For what it is worth, A*T^2=T^2*B.